# Arduino: Generating CRC with FastCRC library (concatenating the uint32_t crc)

Tags: arduino, crc, uint8t, uint32

I'm using the FastCRC library for generating the CRC, and it returns an uint32_t;

```
uint32_t crc = CRC32.crc32(buf, sizeof(buf));
```

The buf, which contains the message, is a uint8_t and I need to append the `uint32_t crc` at the end of the buf. The buf looks like:

```
uint8_t buf[] = {0x7E, 0x00, 0x78, 0xF0, 0x7E};
```

How do I iterate through the CRC to append it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the shift `>>` and and `&` operators to extract the four bytes from the integer.

Comment: Would you mind to give an example? I'm new with this kind of operators.